# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $a_n$ positive sequence.

I think I can prove one direction, but not both.

Comment: Which direction?

Comment: Any assumptions on $a_n$? (are they complex numbers, real numbers, positive numbers?)

Comment: Which direction you proved? How?

Comment: @Wojowu real numbers

Comment: @YoavR. In this case $a_n=-2$ would form a counterexample. I believe you intend the numbers to be positive as well.

Comment: $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} <\infty$ - this is pretty straight forward as $a_n > \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$

Comment: $\Rightarrow$ seems pretty obvious, just use the comparison test.  So I assume it's $\Leftarrow$ you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Wojowu - as you can see - $a_n$ positive sequence - as I already said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<a_n$, thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\infty$. On the other hand, let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\infty$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=0$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. So there is $N>0$ such that $a_n<1$ when $n\ge N$. From this, we have
$$ \frac{1}{2}a_n\le\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}, \text{ for }n\ge N $$
which implies  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.

Comment: Can't figure out this thing you wrote: "Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=0$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$"

Comment: @YoavR., you can prove this fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: can you show me a proof(or even intuition)?

Comment: @YoavR., ok. Clearly if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=0$, then $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, say, $a_n\le M$ for all $n\ge 1$. Thus $\frac{1}{1+M}a_n\le\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$