# Suppose $a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, infinite-product

Suppose $a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.

*Hint:* Use the fact that for any $a>0$, $$a>\ln(1+a)>\frac{a}{1+a}.$$

Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$. By the hint, $$\infty> \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n>\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)>\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}.$$ So $$\infty>\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n).$$
By the limit comparison test $$\infty> \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n).$$ This implies that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$$ converges.

How would I go from the other direction?

Comment: Hint: You haven't used yet that $\log(1+a_n)>\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$. Show that if $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: is what I have for one direction ok?

Comment: It's somewhat sloppy, language-wise, but it is basically correct.

Comment: Related: [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286258/sum-n-1-infty-a-n-infty-if-and-only-if-sum-n-1-infty-fraca-n1a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the other direction, notice that necessarily $a_n\to0$ because $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ converges. Hence,
$$
\frac12<\frac1{1+a_n}<2
$$
for all sufficiently large $n$. So, by comparison, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n/(1+a_n)$ does (and the last one converges because $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ does).