# Showing the infinite product of a sequence does not converge to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x_{n}) > 0$ if $x_{n} \in [0, 1)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n} < \infty$.

So far I used the inequality $1 + t \leq e^{t}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ to bound $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x_{n}) \leq e^{M}$ for some $M$. Then I just quicky used the Monotone Convergence Theorem as the product is montone decreasing to conclude that the product converges. However, I am having troubles showing that it does not converge to $0$ and therefore $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x_{n}) > 0$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose $1&gt;a_n&gt;0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n&lt;\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649989/suppose-1a-n0-for-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-prod-n-1-infty-1-a-n) **or** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649878/suppose-a-n0-for-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-prod-n-1-infty-1a-n-c?rq=1 **or** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650202/suppose-1a-n0-for-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-prod-n-1-infty-1-a-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think it is closely related but my problem is to so that not only does it converge but it converges to a non zero value.

Comment: Check once again all the links, the first link has **iff** answer.

Comment: After your edit I saw the 3rd link. There is a proof showing that the $\prod_{n=1}(1-x_n) =0$ occurs when the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} = \infty$. I don’t think this is enough for my question.

Comment: also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532080/prod-k-1-infty-1-1-2k-converge-to-zero/3532167   since $x_i\in [0,1)$ this problem has a probabilistic flavor and the union bound is the nicest way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n<\infty\ $, then $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0\ $, so there is a positive integer $\ N\ $ such that $\ x_n\le\frac{1}{2}\ $ for $ n\ge N\ $.  Then
$$
1-x_n\ge e^{-2x_n}\ \text{ for }\ n\ge N.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=N}^{N+m}\left(1-x_n\right)&\ge e^{-2\sum_{n=N}^{N+m}x_n}\\
&\ge e^{-2\sum_{n=N}^\infty x_n}\ ,
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=N}^\infty\left(1-x_n\right)&\ge  e^{-2\sum_{n=N}^\infty x_n}\\
&>0\ .
\end{align}
Since $\ \prod_\limits{n=1}^{N-1}\left(1-x_n\right)>0\ $, it follows that $\ \prod_\limits{n=1}^\infty\left(1-x_n\right)>0\ $.

Comment: I really liked this proof. In particular how you broke the product up into two pieces: finite and infinite part. How did you come up with $1-x_n\ge e^{-2x_n}\ \text{ for }\ n\ge N$. This was the most useful part.

Comment: I had a vague recollection that the result could be proved by taking logarithms, although I don't recall whether I have ever seen such a proof. On writing down the inequality
$$
\ln(1−x)\ge−\frac{x}{1−x}
$$
I realised that the tail of $\ \sum_n\ln(1−x_n)\ $ could be bounded below by that of  $\ −K\sum_nx_n\ $ for some constant $\ K\ $. Splitting the product isn't really necessary, though. If  $\ K=\frac{1}{1−\sup_n x_n}\ $, then
$$
\prod_\limits{n=1}^\infty\left(1-x_n\right)> e^{-K\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n}\ .
$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\sum x_n < +\infty \Longrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_n = 0$$

so
$$-\ln(1-x_n) \sim x_n$$

so by comparison, the series $\sum \ln(1-x_n)$ converges to a limit $L$, so
$$\prod_{n=1}^N (1-x_n) = \exp \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \ln(1-x_n)\right)$$

converges when $N$ tends to $+\infty$ to $$\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-x_n) = \exp(L) >0$$

Comment: Great downvote ! Any reason ?

Comment: I did not downvote you. My question got downvoted also with no reason.